# js event in a handlebars template

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

When i click on a button, my template who have a table is feeded.

I want to do an action when i double click to a row of a table in a handlebar template.

```
<body>
<script id="lodgerSearchResult-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="span12">
    <table id="lodgerSearchResultTable" data-show-header="true" class="table" data-toggle="table" data-height="250">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Date de naissance</th>
    <th>N.A.S.</th>
    <th>N.A.M.</th>
    <th>Immeuble</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       {{#each this}}
       <tr>
         ...
         ...
       </tr>
       {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
</body>



<script>
   $('#lodgerSearchResultTable > tbody').dblclick(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
   });
</script>
```

Actually, nothing happen.

Edit: i put the double click event in the ajax success answer

```
$('#lodgerSearch').on('click', function (e) {

    var searchParam = $('#srch-term').val();
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/lodgers/search";
    if (searchParam != "") {
        url = "http://localhost:8080/lodgers/search?searchTemp=" + searchParam;
    }

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

            $("#lodgerSearchResult").empty().append(template(data));
            // is the line i added
            $('#lodgerSearchResultTable > tbody').dblclick(function () {
                alert($(this).text());
            });

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status) {
            // error handler
            alert("error " + jqXHR + " -  " + status);
        }
    });
    // e.preventDefault();
});
```

Is there a cleaner way to do the same thing?

Comment: test code with `console.log( $('#lodgerSearchResultTable') );` at the beginig of the second script block. Looks like table is not created at this moment. Assign event handler when [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: ok i clicked on my button, templated is loaded... clicked on a row of the table... nothing happen, with your console log, i got table with one row... i put in the console my code about the dblclick and that worked... so don't know where i need to put this code... to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i mean:

```
<script>
  alert('table before: ' + String($('#lodgerSearchResultTable')));
  $( document ).ready(function() {
     alert('table after: ' + String($('#lodgerSearchResultTable')));
     $('#lodgerSearchResultTable > tbody').dblclick(function () {
        alert($(this).text());
     });
  });
</script>
```

other non-clear solution

```
<script>

  $( document ).ready(function() {

     $('#lodgerSearchResult').dblclick(function (event) {

        console.log(event.target);

        var res_table = $('#lodgerSearchResultTable > tbody');
        if( res_table ) {
            alert(res_table.text());
        }
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: template is not yet feed... like i said, template is int the page., user click on the button to search something, ajax call is made, template is rendered. After if the user click on a row of the table i want to do an action: i post most code here: https://jsfiddle.net/4L4b8LLc/

Comment: ok i got it... will edit my post... but i found the solution ugly... if somebody have a better solution in js...